# Trying to identify type of mint

Tags: identification, mint

Given to me by a neighbor here in mexico city, smells more menthol than regular mint. Leaves are covered by a soft fur
And stem is hairy and round, not square. For some reason, pic will not upload.

Comment: Maybe your picture needs resizing, but we do need to see a photo

Comment: Welcome!! Do you need instructions as to how to post your picture? We'd be happy to help. If it almost posts but then you get an error message, let us know what it says. If need be, you can just put a link in your question. That way we can at least see it, and one of us might be able to download it for you. Pictures are not always easy with our system, so let us know if it's still not working!

Comment: This sounds like a plant I have called a "Vicks plant"

Comment: Are you certain the stems aren't square? A plant from the mint family (Lamiaceae) might have rounder stems nearer the end of the growing tips but if you feel down closer to the soil end, the square stem can be seen or felt.